# NSURLSession resume from crash

Tags: ios, swift, download, nsurlsession

Has anyone got any tips on how to reconnect to a download in a NSURLSession after a crash.

If my app crashes, I believe the download continues on the device anyway, and then when my app relaunches I can use the same sessionID in:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfiguration(sessionID)
```

However, am I then supposed to call 'session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler' to see if there are any tasks? The docs aren't clear.

My UI has a download progress bar for each file download, so ideally when I relaunch the app, it would try and reconnect and hook the progress back up to the UI.

At the moment what is happening is I restart the download, and my progress bar flickers because there are 2 downloads in progress - the old one and a new one, and then it gets itself into a state...

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I found, in the [URL System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44):

> In both iOS and OS X, when the user relaunches your app, your app
>   should immediately create background configuration objects with the
>   same identifiers as any sessions that had outstanding tasks when your
>   app was last running, then create a session for each of those
>   configuration objects. These new sessions are similarly automatically
>   reassociated with ongoing background activity.

So once I create the session again and hook up the delegate, the delegate methods start firing again, and I use getTasksWithCompletionHandler to see if there were any tasks in progress and return this to my UI and the rest of the system