# NSURLSession resume from app suspended or crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app that downloads a large file. I have downloaded and run [this sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013416-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple.

Whenever the app is suspended or I rerun from Xcode I am not seeing an output in the log to show the progress of the download.

I have also seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734145/nsurlsession-resume-from-crash)  but I am not seeing how that is translated to code beyond the delegates that are already used in the sample.

Can you please assist on how I can have my app connect to the background download after the app restarts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever the app is suspended or I rerun from Xcode I am not seeing an output in the log to show the progress of the download.

Nor should you expect to.

- If the app is suspended, it is not running; that is what "suspended" means. There is nothing to do any logging; your app is in the deep freeze. If you resume (*not* restart the app from Xcode: rather, tap the suspended app's icon in the Springboard) logging will resume as well. You were never "out of touch" with the download; you were just asleep.
- If you test by restarting from Xcode while your app is still running or suspended, the system regards that as a signal to stop the background download.

So how on earth are you going to test what happens when your app actually *terminates* during the download? The way to test that is to run on a device and *crash* your app during the download. (IIRC, Apple's example provides a button that lets you do that.) In that situation, the background download will continue. You then launch your app again *from the device* (not from Xcode). You now won't get console messages in Xcode, but you *will* get them in the Window > Devices console for this device.

And you will then see that, if you have correctly implemented `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`, it is called. If you then recreate the background session, your task delegate methods will be called. You are back in touch with the background session.

Comment: I have a working example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p846backgroundDownload/ch37p1100backgroundDownload/AppDelegate.swift But it's now written in Swift so it might not do you any good. Still, it's a downloadable project, so you could download it and build and run it on your device and see that what I'm saying is true.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let me try your suggestions.